# If a,b,c,d are natural numbers such that $a^d+b^d=c^d$, which of the following are true?

Tags: number-theory

[image: Find the minimum or maximum value]

**MyApproach**

I took an assumption that let $4^2$ + $3^2$=$5^2$.

Then, According to what I made assumption.option A satisfies the Ans.Hence,A is correct.

> Can Anyone guide me is this correct approach to solve this problem?

Comment: Your example shows that (B), (C), and (D) are false.

Comment: @BrianO  Yes,I could not generate a more structured approach.

Comment: Finding a counter example is a valid way to disprove something. You have an appropriate counter example, just show that each of (B), (C), and (D) are false for your example, so you have to answer (A).

Comment: No, it's fine. That's all the structure you need — after all, it's a multiple-choice question :) I guess "natural number" means "> 0", otherwise $a=1, b=0,c=1$ makes (A) false too.